# TCP Sampler : Getting JMeter error : Response message:org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 765

Tags: tcp, jmeter

Getting JMeter error : Response message:org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 765

Below is the configuration :

TCPClient classname : TCPClientImpl
ip
port
Re-use connection - Yes
Close connection - No
Set NoDelay - No
SO_LINGER - 0
EOL - 0
connect - 10000
Response - 10000

Beanshell PreProcessor Script

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.*;

String textToSend = "\n";
String fline = "";

    FileReader fR = new FileReader("C:/Users/prakashr/Desktop/prakash.txt");
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);

    while((fline = bR.readLine())!= null){
        textToSend =  fline + textToSend;
    }
sampler.setRequestData(textToSend);
log.info("Text :"+textToSend);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter returns "Error reading from server" message when an [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) occurs and should print the message/root cause/stacktrace to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

So you need to inspect this exception details in order to determine the root cause.

It would also be a good idea to [enable debug logging for the TCP protocol package](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp" level="debug" />
```

this way you will be able to see more verbose information regarding what's going on in the log file, it will include the response data as well.

If you can successfully send the message to the server using other TCP client like [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients) you can use an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the data from the telnet client and JMeter so you can compare the requests, identify the differences and amend JMeter configuration to match the telnet client setup.

---

Few more hints:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. [You should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)
3. You don't even need any scripting at all, if you need to send text from a text file you can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function directly in the TCP Sampler's "Text to send" input

Comment: this is the full log